# Reference to double and double returned by operator[] methods with the same argument signature

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I was reading an article on expression templates on Wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates#Motivation_and_example

In this section there are two public methods:

```
double &operator[](size_t i)      { return elems[i]; }
double operator[](size_t i) const { return elems[i]; }
```

The first one appears to return a non-const reference to a double, while the second returns a const double. How can both of these methods exist within the same class?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot distinguish by return type alone, but you can have different member functions distinguished by whether or not they operate on `const` instances of the object.

An example using the code in the link:

```
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>

class Vec {
    std::vector<double> elems;

public:
    Vec(size_t n) : elems(n) {}

    double &operator[](size_t i) { return elems[i]; }
    double operator[](size_t i) const { return elems[i]; }
    size_t size()               const { return elems.size(); }
};

Vec operator+(Vec const &u, Vec const &v) {
    assert(u.size() == v.size());
    Vec sum(u.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < u.size(); i++) {
        sum[i] = u[i] + v[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    Vec vec1{5};
    auto val1 = vec1[2]; // calls the first
    const Vec vec1r{5};
    auto val1c = vec1r[2]; // calls the second
    return 0;
}
```

> Why can `elems[i]` return a *reference* to a `double` for the one method,
>   and `elems[i]` can return a `double` for the other?

These are different functions:

```
double &operator[](size_t i);
double operator[](size_t i) const;
```

and so may return different types.

> Elems is a `std::vector<double>`. How can `elems[i]` sometimes return a
>   *reference* to a `double` and sometimes return a `double`?

The value is not copied in first case, only the reference is returned. The return value is copied in the second case.

[`std::vector<double>::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) returns a reference in the first case and a `const` reference in the second case. But as mentioned before, the `const` reference received from the `std::vector` in the second case is **copied** as a return value by `Vec`'s function.

Comment: I didn't know that. So, why is there an ampersand in front of the first method?

Comment: @AaronF because grammar allows using confusing notations. the return type is `double&`

Comment: The first one does indeed return a `double &` non-const reference. It might be worth looking up how to read function declarations.

Comment: Elems is an std::vector<double>. How can elems[i] sometimes return a reference to a double and sometimes return a double?

Answer (score 3):

> The first one appears to return a non-const reference to a double,

yes, `double &` is a non-const reference to double.

> while the second returns a const double.

No, it just returns `double`, by value.

> How can both of these methods exist within the same class?

The `const` qualifies the *method*, not the return type. You can overload on const-qualification.

Consider the `this` pointer as an implicit argument - you can overload the method depending on whether or not it points to a `const` object, just as for any other argument.

---

For example, these overloads are legal, but because they're overloaded on the parameter type, not the return type. (Once you have a permissible overload, you can certainly have different return types, it just isn't sufficient).

```
int  deref(const int *p) { return *p; }
int& deref(int *p)       { return *p; }

const int i = 42;
int j = deref(&i); // ok, returns by value
// deref(&i) = 24; // not ok, assigns to temporary
deref(&j) = 24;    // ok again, this uses the second overload
assert(i == 42);
assert(j == 24);
```

Exactly the same applies to methods, but using different syntax (the `this` pointer is implicit, so you can't write it out as a parameter with/without `const` directly)

Answer (score 1):

A `const` at the end of a member function declaration means that it is callable when the object of the class is `const`.  (It does not apply to the return type.)

So the expression `v[i]` calls the first if `v` is not `const`-qualified, or the second if `v` is `const`-qualified.